# Referencing a directory outside of current directory. "Modules does not exist in the module map." in node/react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, directory, package.json

I have the following directory structure

```
Apps
|--ComponentLibrary
|----package.json
|--MyProject1
|----package.json
|--MyProject2
|----package.json
```

I want to be able to use components from ComponentLibrary in MyProject1 like:

**MyProject1/App.js**

```
import {Button} from 'ComponentLibrary/components/button';
```

Is there a way I can alias ComponentLibrary in MyProject1? I imagine there's some flag I can add in package.json

Currently I get the following expected error

> Modules does not exist in the module map

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: @ChaimFriedman looks interesting! I'll check it out. thanks!